# CUDA and Eclipse: How can I tell eclipse that <<< (or >>>) is part of the syntax?

Tags: c++, eclipse, cuda

So far I figured out that one can prevent Eclipse from complaining about proprietary CUDA keywords by defining them if `__CDT_PARSER__` is defined. The following code prevents Eclipse from complaining about most of the CUDA keywords.

```
// Prevent eclipse from bitching about unknown keywords
#ifdef __CDT_PARSER__
#define __global__
#define __device__
#define __host__
#define __shared__
#endif
```

This however does not work with the brackets used to configure kernel launches, since my kernels usually have long argument lists this is annoying. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that will work with Eclipse CDT, Visual Studio or Qt Creator This is my solution:

```
#if (defined __CDT_PARSER__) || (defined __INTELLISENSE__) || (defined Q_CREATOR_RUN)
#define __global__
#define __device__
#define __host__
#define __shared__
#define CUDA_KERNEL_DIM(...)

#else
#define CUDA_KERNEL_DIM(...)  <<< __VA_ARGS__ >>>

#endif
```

Then invoke kernels with:

```
myKernel CUDA_KERNEL_DIM(gridDim, blockDim) (foo, bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use a new "Nsight Eclipse Edition" that will be a part of CUDA Toolkit 5.0 and on.